# Is there a way to know which button was pressed without making a new handler in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, electron

I want to use the same button handler for a vanilla JS script. Is there a way to use something like an event handler to get the ID of the button which was pressed, and pass that into the subroutine?

Pseudocode to get the point across

```js
document.addEventListener('buttonClick', (event) => {
    drawComponent(event.clientX, event.clientY, event.buttonID);
})
```

I'm using ASP.Net MVC, electron, and the Razor View Engine if that's relavent.

Comment: event.button: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428562/how-to-get-javascript-event-source-element

Comment: @ControlAltDel I didn't mean mouse button, I meant a HTML button. Apologies for confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event.target

```
document.addEventListener('buttonClick', (event) => {
    console.log("element: " + event.target);
    drawComponent(event.clientX, event.clientY, event.buttonID);
})
```